# WhatsApp launcher for pirated WhatsApp applications

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to launch WhatsApp  via my flutter app using url launcher but I'm not able because I'm using a pirated WhatsApp  calles GB whatsapp is there a way to get it to launch despite of the kind of WhatsApp  application

Answer (score 3):

First of all, It is called a Modded application not pirated.

It is possible but it requires you to have all the modded WhatsApp package names.

> https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps

Using this plug-in we can query all the installed apps in the device. Once you have the list of apps installed, you can check it against the package name and launch it.

Pseudo Code:

```
bool isGBInstalled = await DeviceApps.isAppInstalled('com.whatsapp.gb'); //id of modded whatsapp

if(isGBInstalled){
   DeviceApps.openApp('com.whatsapp.gb');
  }else{
   DeviceApps.openApp('com.whatsapp.app'); //open normal whatsapp
}
```

PS: Avoid supporting modded versions of any applications because they usually contain security flaws that can be exploited easily. Plus on iOS, you can't sideload any app unless you jailbreak. So try to avoid using/supporting modded applications.